# Answered questions showing up in "Unanswered" list

Tags: support

I've noticed there are often questions with posted answers showing in the "unanswered" list of questions. Does anyone know why this is?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to Questions > Unanswered I think that will show you any questions that have no upvoted answers. For the most part this makes sense as, unless the answers were posted very recently, the fact that they have received no votes suggests that the question is still in need of a decent response.

If you want a more strict filter then use the Unanswered > No Answers option.

[image: No Answers]